# WSO2: Add IBM MQ Correllation ID to message header

Tags: wso2, ibm-mq, mq, wso2-esb

How do you add the **IBM MQ Correlation ID header** to a message in WSO2 Integrator?

I have a scenario where I receive a message from MQ, transform the message using a few mediators and calls to backend services, and need to reply with the transformed message to another (MQ) queue using WSO2 Integrator (version 6.1.1). The client receiving the message is expecting to find the same Correlation ID in my reply as in his original message.

IBM tells me the property is this one:

> The CorrelationId to be included in the MQMD of a message when put on
> a queue.
>
> Defined in: MQMessage class
>
> Data Type: String of 24 characters
>
> Syntax: To get: correlid$ = MQMessage.CorrelationId To set: MQMessage.CorrelationId = correlid$

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q034650_.htm

Comment: I suspect you can use the JMS_COORELATION_ID for that: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Axis2+Properties#Axis2Properties-JMS_Coorelation_IDJMS_COORELATION_ID

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and revert.

Comment: Hi Awan, how would I do that exactly in WSO2 Integrator?

Comment: @PetteriPertola as Jan mentioned above, you might follow instruction on that link.

Comment: Hi Awan, the link above does not provide an example of how to cast to MQMessage. Are you able to show an example? The WSO2 documentation in general is often lacking clear examples.

Comment: @PetteriPertola I am not sure of WSO2. But MQMessage class and MQMD are for IBM MQ for Java classes.  If your mom program uses IBM MQ for Java classes, than you will able to set correlationId  at MQMessage.

Comment: That does not help me since i need to set it inside wso2, sorry.

Comment: Hi @Jan - i am trying to attach the ID as above, however on the receiving end of the MQ the correllation ID is missing. So it does not look like WSO2 is setting it correctly.

Comment: Thanks all - the solution was simple. The scope MUST be axis2 when setting JMS_COORELATION_ID property. Any other scope does not work. My scope was set to default or to transport and hence nothing was taking effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was an easy solution. The JMS_COORELATION_ID property must be set specifically in the **axis2 scope**.

So while this works:

```
<property name="JMS_COORELATION_ID" value="MyCoorelationId" scope="axis2" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
```

Using any other scope, such as default or transport, does not:

```
<property name="JMS_COORELATION_ID" value="MyCoorelationId" scope="transport" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
<property name="JMS_COORELATION_ID" value="MyCoorelationId" scope="default" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
```

Unfortunately the WSO2 documentation is dreadful and does not mention that other scopes do not work. Hope this saves someone time in the future.